# How do I get specific properties with Get-AdUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have the following PS script written:

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users & Computers, DC=aaaaaaa, DC=com' -Properties DisplayName  | Export-CSV "ADUsers.csv"`

From what I can tell it should be returning only DisplayName.  It's returning everything though.  Problem is that DistinguishedName is causing truncation problems later on in my process.  How can I get the script to only return certain properties?

Answer (score 16):

using `select-object` for example:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users & Computers, DC=aaaaaaa, DC=com' -Properties DisplayName | select -expand displayname | Export-CSV "ADUsers.csv"
```

Comment: hmmm... that returned an error:  ArgumnetNull.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand.

Comment: I'm looking into the syntax for Select-Object though.  If it works I'll post the script.

Comment: the error says that the user in the pipe have not set a displayname.Try removing the `-expand`

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users & Computers, DC=aaaaa, DC=com' -Properties  EmployeeNumber,GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, OfficePhone, PostalCode, City, StreetAddress, Office,Company, Title, SID | select  EmployeeNumber,GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, OfficePhone, PostalCode, City, StreetAddress, Office,Company, Title,SID | Export-CSV "../SSIS/Import Data/ADUsers.csv"

Comment: `select` isn't mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2012r2-ps)... What if there are multiple properties?

Comment: `get-aduser user1 -properties PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet | select -expand PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet`
***Select-Object** : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.*

Comment: `get-aduser user1 -properties PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet | select -expand PasswordExpired -expand PasswordLastSet` : ***Select-Object** : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'ExpandProperty' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".*

Comment: @samis same thing as above; remove `-expand`

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me as well:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=OU,dc=Domain,dc=com" -Properties Enabled, CanonicalName, Displayname, Givenname, Surname, EmployeeNumber, EmailAddress, Department, StreetAddress, Title | select Enabled, CanonicalName, Displayname, GivenName, Surname, EmployeeNumber, EmailAddress, Department, Title | Export-CSV "C:\output.csv"
```